# How can I open very large files with good performance?

Tags: large-documents

I have server log files that are several gigabytes in size (on Ubuntu). When I attempt to open them, the terminal locks up for a minute or so while the file is loaded into Vim. Is there a way to reduce this time, for example by setting Vim to load the file on demand, or by some other method?

Comment: Why not use `less`?

Comment: Do you intend to manipulate the files in any way, or do you just want to view them?

Comment: I would like to edit the files.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19795855/732016

Comment: Most likely I will get banned from the site forever but I have to say it: when it comes to work with huge files Emacs is the tool for the job. :-)

Comment: Why not consider ed for large files?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

First, try loading vim with no plugins or vimrc:

```
vim -u NONE gargantuan.txt
```

If this is substantially faster, then you probably have syntax highlighting, folding, plugins, or something else going on that's taking up most of the time.
Try turning stuff off in your vimrc (and disabling your plugins) until you find the culprit.

Also make sure to `set ft= syn=` and `syntax off`.

If this doesn't help, it's probably the case that you have very long *lines* that are causing the problem.
Try `set nowrap` to turn line wrapping off.

Comment: `vim -U NONE -N gargantuan.txt` will do the same thing while running vim in `nocompatible` which runs in "vi iMproved" mode instead of trying to be compatible with the old "vi"

Answer (score 27):

Vim is the wrong tool for the job: you should use a pager like `more` or `less`.

If you insist on using an editor, try [this example adapted from the Vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Faster_loading_of_large_files):

```
augroup LargeFile
        let g:large_file = 10485760 " 10MB

        " Set options:
        "   eventignore+=FileType (no syntax highlighting etc
        "   assumes FileType always on)
        "   noswapfile (save copy of file)
        "   bufhidden=unload (save memory when other file is viewed)
        "   buftype=nowritefile (is read-only)
        "   undolevels=-1 (no undo possible)
        au BufReadPre *
                \ let f=expand("<afile>") |
                \ if getfsize(f) > g:large_file |
                        \ set eventignore+=FileType |
                        \ setlocal noswapfile bufhidden=unload buftype=nowrite undolevels=-1 |
                \ else |
                        \ set eventignore-=FileType |
                \ endif
augroup END
```

Comment: Can `less` or `more` also make changes to my file?

Comment: They can't, of course. Logs are not meant to be edited.

Comment: [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) was invented for this purpose. You figure out which changes you want to make, expressed as substitutions, then run `sed` to perform them. This also works on streams (i.e. file content that has no end because it is being produced).

Comment: I have aliased `less`, `more` and `man` to `vimpager`.
https://github.com/rkitover/vimpager

Answer (score 10):

The LargeFile.vim plugin is designed to make editing large files faster.  See http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#LARGEFILE .

From the page:

> Allows much quicker editing of large files (default: 100MB+ are "large"), at the price of turning off events, undo, syntax highlighting, etc. Also available at vim.sf.net where you may rank it.

According to the manual, the plugin works just by having it installed. You can set the cutoff by changing `g:LargeFile`, to an integer number of MB, which it says defaults to 20MB (in contrast to the project description which says 100)

The plugin also provides commands `:UnLarge`, `:Large` and `:Large!` to disable, reenable, or force enable (for small files) respectively on the currently loaded file.

Answer (score 4):

I have heard that turning off syntax highlighting can help:

```
:syntax off
```

Comment: Having any kind of folding enabled also has a massive effect

Answer (score 0):

Another pager you may like to try is `most`:
http://www.jedsoft.org/most/

Also, rotate your logs and as this may contribute to less larger logs.