# vim :wq! on file with read-only permissions after escaping loading loses information in that file

Tags: save

I have a large file, about `1.5 Gb`. When opening the file in vim, I typically will `ctrl-c` escape the buffering so I don't have to wait for the whole file to load. For one particular file, it was modified by a prepackaged program, which subsequently made it made read-only.

I needed to edit this file somewhere near the beginning, so I did so and then saved it using `:wq!` (as prompted to do so by vim). When I exited, I noticed that the file had decreased in size from about `1.5Gb` to `~200Mb`. I believe it only saved what it had loaded before I exited with `:wq!`.

Is this a known behavior of vim? It seems like a bad design flaw that it would tell you to exit with `wq!` when a file is read-only, but not warn you that it won't write what hasn't buffered yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what is the question here, but this is a known behaviour.
This is the reason why loading only part of the file (with `ctrl-c` as you did) opens the file in read-only mode, to prevent data losses like the one you described.

You can find more information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908575/how-to-edit-multi-gigabyte-text-files-vim-doesnt-work

Answer (score 2):

Control + C in Vim means the same as in the shell: "cancel everything you're doing as soon as possible". This includes cancelling actually reading the file

When you open a file, Vim will load it in memory ("a buffer"), and `:w` will write the buffer to disk. If Vim only loaded 200MB in the buffer, it will only write 200MB to disk. This is expected behaviour.

See [How can I open very large files with good performance?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/149/51) for tips on how to improve performance.